# Delete the last entry of groups in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I was hoping to clean my data by deleting the last entry of all groups with the same elements.

my data looks somewhat like this:

```
  type  2   3  
 1 A    2.3 4  
 2 A    3.4 5  
 3 B    5.5 6  
 4 B    6   7 
 5 B    3   7 
 6 C    5   6  
 ....
```

ie. I am trying to get rid of the last entry of every group with the same type, so it will look like this.

```
  type  2   3  
 1 A    2.3 4  
 2 B    5.5 6 
 3 B    6   7 
 4 C    5   6
```

My actual data have different length for each type, and usually over a few hundreds. I thought of group_by and then `last()` but it seems to work only with `summarize`. any idea?

Comment: You could use `df %>% group_by(type) %>% slice(-n())`, though if you have a single row in the group (like `C` above), it will get deleted. You could work around that with `ifelse`, if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another option with `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'type', we check the sequence of row (`row_number()`) is not equal to the number of rows (`n()`- corresponds to the last row number as well) or `|`) if the number of rows is equal to 1 (`n()==1`).  So, basically, we are removing the last row by creating the logical index (`row_number() !=n()`) along with an exception to handle the cases where there is only a single row (`n()==1`).

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(type) %>%
    filter(row_number()!=n()|n()==1)
#  type   `2`   `3`
#  <chr> <dbl> <int>
#1     A   2.3     4
#2     B   5.5     6
#3     B   6.0     7
#4     C   5.0     6
```

Comment: it works i think! could you explain a bit on  ` filter(row_number()!=n()|n()==1)` ?

Answer (score 5):

Let `dat` be your data frame, you may use

```
dat[duplicated(dat$type, fromLast = TRUE), ]
```

where `duplicated(, fromLast = TRUE)` will find duplicates backward.

---

**Example**

```
set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(type = sort(sample(LETTERS[1:4], 12, TRUE)), x = 1:12)

#   type  x
#1     A  1
#2     A  2
#3     A  3
#4     B  4
#5     B  5
#6     C  6
#7     C  7
#8     C  8
#9     D  9
#10    D 10
#11    D 11
#12    D 12

dat[duplicated(dat$type, fromLast = TRUE), ]

#   type  x
#1     A  1
#2     A  2
#4     B  4
#6     C  6
#7     C  7
#9     D  9
#10    D 10
#11    D 11
```

Comment: my actually data has different length for each type instead of just two, then `duplicated` won't work right?

Comment: I tried, but it seems that instead of getting rid of the last one for each type, only the first entry for each type remained..

Comment: i think i will go with the other approach, really thanks for your patience though :)